# epson stylus office bx305fw plus How to scan

Tags: printing, epson

I have a [epson stylus office bx305fw plus](http://www.epson.nl/nl/nl/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/specs/11089), But i don't now where the scan option is in the default printer application in Ubuntu

How can i scan with my printer?

Answer (score 2):

I just got my Epson Stylus Office bx305fw plus to scan using simple scan. I plugged in to the printer/all in one via usb and the scan worked I then tried it wirelessly and it worked. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and a thinkpad t61.I had downloaded the epson driver from here http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escpr/
I hope this helps.
Tiernan

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this may not answer your question it will certainly get you started.

"simple-scan" is what I use for a similar HP scanner/printer. You may need to install it, I can't remember if it's installed by default.

This will tell you if the scanner is detected by your computer.

You can also type `dmesg` in a terminal after you plug in the scanner and see what the kernel is telling you about the hardware and driver situation.

From that message you can Google for solutions.

Richard

Comment: Thank you but i tried simple-scan before.(it didn't find my scanner) about dmesg ill try that as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

[Download Printer Driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16831&DSCCHK=c31134dce749eae1495544f089354a46dea9533d)  ESC/P Driver (full feature)

**Product name:**   Epson Stylus Office BX305
**Driver-Version:** Ver. latest(02-2012)

---

[Older Drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult) just in case! Search query: BX305

In addition you can download useful packages, using `synaptic package-manager`, to monitor your ink-level and printer status.