# Linux driver for the Epson Style Office BX305F printer/scanner?

Tags: printing

I have not been able to print or scan with my Epson Style Office BX305F on Ubuntu. I've tried adding a printer and using simple scan but neither work.

Comment: Also refer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186871/epson-stylus-office-bx305fw-plus-how-to-scan/368047#368047

Answer (score 0):

You can download drivers via the following website:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 0):

[Download Printer Driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16831&DSCCHK=c31134dce749eae1495544f089354a46dea9533d)  ESC/P Driver (full feature)

**Product name:**   Epson Stylus Office BX305
**Driver-Version:** Ver. latest(02-2012)

---

[Older Drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult) just in case! Search query: `BX305` and choose `Linux` OS

[image]

If you're not sure how to install the driver after downloading it, simply download the `.deb` (which is optional) and double-click on it, which then is opened within USC <sub>(Ubuntu Software Center).</sub> Use the `Install` -option and you are good to go!

---

In addition you can download useful packages, using `synaptic package-manager`, to monitor your ink-level and printer status.